# Override eloquent relationship result data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I use [Laravel-Metable](https://github.com/plank/laravel-metable) package in my project. This package return collection object using in key `meta` name and on value `eloquent` object.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUkD0.jpg) you can see package data result screenshot.

How I can override result data and get this type of array data:

```
$meta = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'key' => "Meta Name",
        'value' => "Meta Value"

    ],

    [
        'id' => 2,
        'key' => "Meta Name",
        'value' => "Meta Value"

    ],
];
```

I will load my models meta with lazy loading:

```
use Metable;

protected $with = ['meta'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the collection [map](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-map) method for that so it should be something like this:

```
$result = $metaItems->map(function($meta) {
    return [
        'id' => $meta->id,
        'key' => $meta->key,
        'value' => $meta->value
    ];
})->values();

// then $result->toArray(); should give you the expected result
```

Comment: I was using the screenshot that you provided as the `$metaItems` result and applied the code on those. But you can add this in the model.

Comment: Now you result is like [this](https://i.imgur.com/qLBoUgJ.jpg) but I need to [result](https://3v4l.org/d1fGv) wihtout using meta names on parent array keys. I need replace keys to default array numbers. @nakov

Comment: @AndreasHunter consider accepting it if it helped :)